# Autocomplete search in jQuery mobile

Tags: jquery-mobile, autocomplete

I need to do an autocomplete search in jQuery mobile like [this one](http://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/).

But I can only find [this](http://demos.jquerymobile.com/1.3.0-rc.1/docs/demos/widgets/autocomplete/).

I would like the options to appear above the text. I would like to use jQuery mobile 1.2.0. Thank you.

Comment: check this http://www.raymondcamden.com/index.cfm/2012/3/27/Example-of-Autocomplete-in-jQuery-Mobile